# Nested pivoting

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

last time you taught me pivoting using SELECT CASE and it was extremely helpful.
This time I need help in something more advanced.

The situation is as follows:

I have the same old death record database; the column storing causes contains values for all the causes and I made to turn it into n columns for n causes using select case, like this

```
SELECT anno, cod_comune,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
SUM(CASE cod_tit WHEN 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_I,
SUM(CASE cod_tit WHEN 'II' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_II ,
SUM(CASE cod_tit WHEN 'III' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_III,
...
FROM casi 
WHERE cod_comune>40000 AND cod_comune<200000 AND cod_comune NOT LIKE '%00'
GROUP BY anno, cod_comune, sex
ORDER BY anno, cod_comune, age;
```

By doing this I obtain 2 rows for every city, one for males and one for females and the number of people dead by each of the causes.

That is, I get something like this

```
+------+------------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+
| anno | cod_comune | M    | F    | dis_I | dis_II | dis_III |
+------+------------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+
| 2003 |      41001 |    0 |   19 |     0 |      5 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41001 |   20 |    0 |     0 |      7 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41002 |   12 |    0 |     0 |      3 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41002 |    0 |   16 |     0 |      6 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41003 |    8 |    0 |     0 |      1 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41003 |    0 |    6 |     0 |      2 |       0 |
| ...  |      ...   |  ... |  ... |   ... |    ... |     ... |
```

Instead, my professor said that it would be desirable if I had only 1 row for each town, keeping anyway the gender distinction.

So, I tought to double the columns related to the causes, for example causeI_m and causeI_f. I've given two conditions to select case but it doesn't work, among the causes I have all zeros.

```
SELECT anno, cod_comune,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'M' AND cod_tit='I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_Im,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'M' AND cod_tit='II' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_IIm ,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'M' AND cod_tit='III' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_IIIm,
...
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'F' AND cod_tit='I'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_If,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'F' AND cod_tit='II'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_IIf ,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'F' AND cod_tit='III'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_IIIf,
...
FROM casi 
WHERE cod_comune>40000 AND cod_comune<200000 AND cod_comune NOT LIKE '%00'
GROUP BY anno, cod_comune, sex
ORDER BY anno, cod_comune, age;
```

I get from this query

```
+------+------------+------+------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| anno | cod_comune | M    | F    | dis_Im | dis_IIm | dis_If | dis_IIf |
+------+------------+------+------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 2003 |      41001 |   20 |   19 |      0 |       0 |      0 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41002 |   12 |   16 |      0 |       0 |      0 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41003 |    8 |    6 |      0 |       0 |      0 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41004 |    7 |    5 |      0 |       0 |      0 |       0 |
| 2003 |      41005 |    2 |    5 |      0 |       0 |      0 |       0 |
| ...  |      ...   |  ... |  ... |   ...  |   ...   |    ... |  ...    |
```

I've tought that I've orderd the database to sum the cases when sex is equal to that modality and the cause is the one I've specified. But something is wrong and I can't figure out what.
I'd be glad if you give me a little help :)
(I hope to have well explained the problem, English is still my second language)

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data to recreate your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think you should remove "sex" column from grouping statement:

```
SELECT anno, cod_comune,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
SUM(CASE sex WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='M' AND cod_tit='I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_M_I,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='M' AND cod_tit='II' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_M_II ,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='M' AND cod_tit='III' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_M_III,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='F' AND cod_tit='I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_F_I,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='F' AND cod_tit='II' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_F_II ,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='F' AND cod_tit='III' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dis_F_III,
...
FROM casi 
WHERE cod_comune>40000 AND cod_comune<200000 AND cod_comune NOT LIKE '%00'
GROUP BY anno, cod_comune  -- !!! No sex here !!!
ORDER BY anno, cod_comune, age;
```

This will stop splitting your rows by sex.

Comment: Yes but removing sex from grouping gives me a single line for each town but there's not anymore distinction between how many males have died by cause x and how many females dead by cause x, I only get the sum of population dead by that cause in that city that year

Comment: Got it, you can use your approach with adding additional columns for each case. See my adjusted answer. I just adjusted the syntax a little to eliminate zeroes you had previously.